# Jerky slideshow transition of scaled images in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

Please have a look at this: http://www.eymy.nl

The transition works smoothly in all browsers, but becomes jerky in Safari when the images are scaled down (when the window height is smaller than 1227 pixels, which is the 100% height of the images). In other words, Safari cannot handle this transition together with scaling.

My guess is that it CAN, but needs different code. I tried different slideshow scripts and the results are always the same, the moment the images are scaled (down OR up) the transition in Safari becomes jerky.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Everything looks fine in Safari, on my end.  Maybe your computer is just having an issue processing it or something?  I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome and Safari on a i7 MacBook Air and it was smoother in chrome. After the first image loaded in Safari which was choppy it looked OK. Since this seems like an issue of images loading before they are animated I would suggest preloading them. This is usually done in the body tag with JavaScript or you can also use CSS. [See this page](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) for ways to preload images.

Comment: Thanks. It's by no means a loading issue. It happens offline as well. Perhaps you're machine is very fast, or your resolution high. Try making the window smaller?